# Description formatting in Jira Python API

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, jira, exasol

I am trying to create a issue in Jira with description containing a dataframe ,i am trying to display the dataframe data in table style but it looks like below when issue is created,display of header is not matching with values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waJFL.png)
description='''{0} '''.format(df)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've a method in https://github.com/dren79/JiraScripting_public - https://github.com/dren79/JiraScripting_public/blob/main/create_jira_tickets/create_fancy_jira_issue.py that will do the job for you. Use the below code (from https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/apis/document/playground/) and substitute "superDataFrame" with your dataframe, you might also have need of https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/, that could format the table nicely?

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "type": "doc",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "This is my fancy description."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "I’m going to put my dataframe in here:"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "codeBlock",
      "attrs": {
        "language": "python"
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "superDataFrame"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```